# Determine CPU on which the calling thread is running?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm new to Pthread. I have written an example to check which CPU my thread is running on.
I have used [sched_getcpu()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sched_getcpu.3.html) to get the number of the CPU on which the calling thread is currently executing. Here is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* a(){

    printf("1st child thread in CPU %d\n",sched_getcpu());

    return NULL;
}

void* b(){

   printf("2nd child thread in CPU %d\n",sched_getcpu());
   
   return NULL;
  
}

void* c(){

   printf("3rd child thread in CPU %d\n",sched_getcpu());
   
   return NULL;
  
}
void* d(){


   printf("4th child thread in CPU %d\n",sched_getcpu());
   
   return NULL;
  
}
void* e(){

    printf("5th child thread in CPU %d\n",sched_getcpu());
   
    return NULL;
  
}

int main(){

     pthread_t t;
     pthread_t t1;
     pthread_t t2;
     pthread_t t3;
     pthread_t t4;

     pthread_create(&t,NULL,a,NULL);
     pthread_create(&t1,NULL,b,NULL);
     pthread_create(&t2,NULL,c,NULL);
     pthread_create(&t3,NULL,d,NULL);
     pthread_create(&t4,NULL,e,NULL);



    pthread_join(t,NULL);
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
    pthread_join(t3,NULL);
    pthread_join(t4,NULL);
    
    printf("main thread in CPU %d\n",sched_getcpu());

    return 0;

}
```

Obviously, the output of this program will change every running time. But here is an example:

Output:

```
1st child thread in CPU 2
3rd child thread in CPU 2
2nd child thread in CPU 0
4th child thread in CPU 3
5th child thread in CPU 1
main thread in CPU 3
```

The id number of the CPU changed from 0 to 3. I wonder why the output was in the range of 0 to 3 while my computer only has 2 cores and 4 threads. Did the id of the CPU in output equaled with the id of the physical thread? Thanks!

Comment: Note: The value returned by `sched_getcpu()` tells you which CPU was running the thread at some particular instant in time, but there's no guarantee that the thread still will be running on that same CPU at any later time. In theory, the thread could lose its time slice, and then be brought back on a different CPU even before `sched_getcpu()` returns. That might not happen often in practice, but by the time the I/O system calls inside the subsequent `printf(...)` complete, there's a significantly better chance that the thread could be running on a different CPU.

Comment: It's very informative. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your computer has 2 cores and 4 "logical processors" (CPUs). Because you have 4 CPUs the ID numbers are from 0 to 3.

The main problem here is terminology - how "CPU" (and "thread") is defined. You're assuming "CPU" is defined as "core", but most people define it as "logical processor" or "(hardware) thread"; and with hyper-threading you have 2 logical processors per core so you end up with 4 CPUs (from 2 cores).

Answer (score 0):

My two cents for pthread beginners:

add:

#include <sched.h>

as per:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sched_getcpu.3.html